# Have I placed these connectors correctly?

Tags: motherboard, orientation

I replaced my motherboard and took out the the following connections without realizing where they go. Have I connected the jumpers correctly on my ASUS H81M-PLUS?

Photos for reference:

Diagram In Motherboard Guide:
[image: Diagram In Motherboard Guide]

Pins Without Jumpers:
[image: Pins Without Jumpers]

Power SW/LED Connected:
[image: Power SW/LED Connected]

HDD/RESET Connected:
[image: HDD/RESET Connected]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: They look off center….

Answer (score 0):

Almost. Your PWR_LED pins are swapped, and I can't be certain about your HDD_LED, it's almost certainly correct but there may be a little + symbol on the bottom, or printed on one or the other of the thin sides possibly, or the red wire on that header - in your picture whichever that is should be towards the left.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell due to the photos of the connectors attached being grayscale, which makes it hard to tell about the color-coding of the cables.

But:

- the orientation printed onto the motherboard shows being in the same direction for both rows
- the orientation is switched for the connectors as you can read the print on them from their respective sides
- the orientation of the Power-LED does not fit the print on the board - plus/minus are swapped

The last point - orientation swapped of Power-LED - leads to the assumption that you have to rotate/switch the connectors so that +/- are as given on the board and therefore also rotate the Power-Switch, so that for both the print would show like for the LEDs on the other row towards the edge of the motherboard (outwards not inwards).